# Is it possible to define a protected property of an internal type in C#?

Tags: c#

I want `InternalClass` to be `internal` (not accessible outside of the assembly)

I also want to define a `protected` property of type `InternalClass` (in the same assembly)

This is what I have:

```
internal class InternalClass 
{
}
```

Now I want to use this type in another class, however it has to be `protected`:

```
public class MyClass
{
   protected internal InternalClass IC { get; }
}
```

The above code gives me the following error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'InternalClass' is less
> accessible than property 'MyClass.IC'

When I check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal), I can see `protected internal` is a valid modifier, but I am not sure  how to use it?

Comment: You might be looking for `private protected` but it's difficult to tell for sure. If your current code worked I could define a class, derived from `MyClass` in a different assembly. And in that class, I'm meant to have access to `IC`, except I'm not allowed to use `InternalClass`. So what do you want to give up? Should types derivable from `MyClass` be definable in other assemblies?

Comment: [This table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#summary-table) is a good summary of the different access modifiers.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine actually, `private protected` is that, as (and I quote) "A private protected member is accessible by types derived from the containing class (protected), but only within its containing assembly (internal)" (parenthesis mine). [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected)

Comment: @MindSwipe I guess you're right. This does seem to be what the OP is after.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini really? Interesting. Using your example as a template [works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y03Lus)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, @MindSwipe: thanks. `private protected` is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that `MyClass` is public, meaning a outside class (one in another assembly) can derive it and then have access to the internal class through the `protected internal` property. This is because `protected internal` is `protected` or `internal`. From the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal):

> A protected internal member is accessible from the current assembly **or** from types that are derived from the containing class.

(emphasis mine)

If you want to keep `MyClass` public, then you'll need to either make `InternalClass` not internal, or make the property `IC` not be accessible from outside by making `IC` be `private protected`. From the MS docs:

> A private protected member is accessible by types derived from the containing class, **but only within its containing assembly**

(emphasis mine)

Which seems like what you want.